# What is correct rich snippet microdata for an Event?

Tags: html

I'm trying to implement microdata for events on my site. When I use the Google Rich Snippet Testing tool I keep getting the error "Insufficient data to generate the preview".

Does anybody know of a definitive list of what data they want?

Is this stuff just too buggy to be spending time implementing now? My goal is to get better SEO results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This :

```
<div>
<a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap">Spinal Tap</a>
<img src="spinal_tap.jpg" />

After their highly-publicized search for a new drummer,
Spinal Tap kicks off their latest comeback tour with a San
Francisco show.

When: Oct 15, 7:00PM—9:00PM

Where: Warfield Theatre, 982 Market St, San Francisco, CA

Category: Concert

</div>
```

Would become :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap" itemprop="url" >

    <span itemprop="summary">Spinal Tap</span>

  </a>
   <img itemprop="photo" src="spinal_tap.jpg" />

  <span itemprop="description">After their highly-publicized search for a new drummer,
   Spinal Tap kicks off their latest comeback tour with a San
   Francisco show.</span>

  When:
  <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 7:00PM</time>—
  <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 9:00PM</time>

  Where:

    <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/​Organization">

    <span itemprop="name">Warfield Theatre</span>

     <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">

         <span itemprop="street-address">982 Market St</span>, 

         <span itemprop="locality">San Francisco</span>, 

         <span itemprop="region">CA</span>

     </span>

     <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/​Geo">
        <meta itemprop="latitude" content="37.774929" />
        <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-122.419416" />
     </span>
  </span>

  Category: <span itemprop="eventType">Concert</span> 
</div>
```

Just make sur you html works in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have similar html, as outlined at schema.org. I'm still trying to figure out what fields are required so I can stop getting the error. I've also seen some info that perhaps it's not just due to certain fields being missing, that it could also be caused by other problems as well.

Comment: All fields are not indeed requiered. But you do have to respect the itemscope itemtype for link details, and itemprop elements. Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Even with a well formatted page with schema.org markup, I've found that Google still relies on some of their older snippet requirements. You can find these requirements for Events at http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506&topic=1088474&ctx=topic . Scroll down to the "Properties" heading and you'll see some marked in bold. Make sure your markup includes those properties

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <a itemprop="url" href="nba-miami-philidelphia-game3.html">
  NBA Eastern Conference First Round Playoff Tickets:
  <span itemprop="name"> Miami Heat at Philadelphia 76ers - Game 3 (Home Game 1) </span>
  </a>
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">
    Thu, 04/21/16
    8:00 p.m.
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <a itemprop="url" href="wells-fargo-center.html">
    Wells Fargo Center
    </a>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Philadelphia</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">PA</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
    Priced from: <span itemprop="lowPrice">$35</span>
    <span itemprop="offerCount">1938</span> tickets left
  </div>
</div>
```

For more details and examples go here http://schema.org/Event , scroll to "Examples", select "Microdata".